# VS 2010: unable to unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I posted this on MSDN as well but this community usually is much more helpful:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/9a2717c7-4d24-4940-b5be-2bc3df6d7c7d

In a nutshell, VS refuses to start the testing agent. The machine is restarted to make sure nothing is in its memory. In other words, VSPerfMon is NOT running and hasn't been run prior.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Added 100 point bounty. I really need to solve this.

Comment: I'm using a customer-hosted VM that has this exact same issue.  Definitely annoying.  Problem seems to come and go. Did you ever figure out a root cause, or did you just live with it?

Comment: Nope. It just disappeared for some reason. Don't know what was that and circumstances that led to it's disappearing. Try @GeorgeJohnston approach.

Answer (score 4):

The problem magically disappeared :( Darn it... Bunch of people experience this every day and there is no answer.

Comment: -1: That is probably one of the most *unacceptable* accepted solutions I've ever seen here in SO. OK, seen worse, but still deserves a downvote.

Comment: Well, it tells the next person who experiences this that the problem will magically disappear over time. As long as that's true, the answer is both accurate and helpful.

Comment: @rsenna: if you follow the link to MSDN, you will see the same "resolution" was found by another person. What do you want me to do? Leave the question open? If I had anything, I'd added that. I don't have anything. The question has been pending for 2 weeks and no responses, by the way.

Comment: @Schultz9999: You are the OP, it's your choice. But, still, magic + an excuse does not sound as a real answer to me.

Comment: @rsenna: all right, un-answered the question. I'll let you know if this question is ever resolved without a steady repro.

Comment: Sounds fine as an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

The important portion of the error messages you're seeing is this:

Failed to get agent process proxy: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any time you see a message containing the key phrase *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* in Visual Studio (or in an event log message originating from Visual Studio) you should read it like this:

Visual Studio integration of this feature has been implemented somewhere on the scale between 'weak' and 'craptacular'.  Shut down Visual Studio, all other processes, reboot the machine, restart Visual Studio, and hope for better results next time.  Or maybe the time after that.  Sorry.

It's just such an enormous product that there's going to always be portions of it that aren't really implemented well.  Those pieces will always stick out badly from an otherwise excellent piece of software.

Comment: Thanks. I did that, which I tried to point out in the question itself: "The machine is restarted to make sure nothing is in its memory". That's what I do under Windows if something is getting fishy. Didn't help this time.

Comment: Indeed, and I also read that the problem was "magically" solved some time after doing the Microsoft Reboot Dance.  I'm sure there was absolutely no connection between the sacred Ritual of Restart and the Magical Disappearance of the problem, I just wanted to point out that this is part of a larger set of difficult problems all with the same root cause: Poor VS integration.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by *removing all of the meta data test files and those with testing extensions in the top level solution directory*.

After many failed attempts to run unit tests, deleting my bin/obj folders, and resetting my machine -- this is the only solution that allowed my tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

look in your list of running processes. If you have something running called (if memory serves) VSPerfMon ... kill it and try to run your tests again.

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned above, the machine is restarted so VSPerfMon is not running.

Comment: oh, you know, you're right ... sorry about that. Hmm, is there an error message that it gives or something?

Comment: All I could dig out is in those EventLog entries (see the link to MSDN post). Other than that I don't see anything. I was trying to see if I can set up an agent somehow but I don't see any test UI tool then mention in the posts (like create controller, etc.).